# Codeigniter/PHP Send SES Email Via API

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-iam

I would like to ask if anyone of you tried using SES to send email using PHP? If so I would like to know what are the needed requirements to accomplish this? Because I tried to research on sending email via SES I encountered a solution using SMTP. But the problem with this is that I need to have an SMTP username and Password. I was given a task to send SES via API Call. I tried looking under amazon documentation but I can't find a clear answer. Anyways I'm doing this task without any given credential like AWS username password or the AWS access key. This was the hard part since I only have limited resources on me that is why I don't know where to start. Some of the example requires an ACCESS KEY or SECRET KEY of some sort. But I don't have any of this. I don't even have the IAM role credential. Also my superior said that my access was granted on IAM role so I can use SES on the server and I need to use API Call for this.

Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this on PHP? Need your help guys. Thanks

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-amazon-ses)!!!

Comment: Does this need any credential? from what I see its only using a unit_test. But i'm worried if this need an AWS ACCESS KEY for this

Answer (score 0):

Your superior needs to create an IAM user with specific permisions for this particular user to be able to use his SES account. This IAM user has an API key and a secret. With this credentials you can use any library which plays hard with the SES API. From what you say, it seems your suoerior has already created the IAM user so you only need the keys and you'll be good to go.
Maybe you want him to give you also SNS access.

Comment: I already asked him about the credential. But he said I don't need to have the username and password credential since I'm not going to use the SES SMTP but instead he want me to use the SES API CALL. Now I don't know what are the needed requirements if I'm going with his suggested approach. As I've researched SES API Call needed the AWS SECRET KEY to be able to send email. But I don't have that credential.